# Unable to switch connection on two headphone devices if connected one turns off swift iOS?

Tags: swift, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on a bluetooth application which works for headphones I am easily able to connect to headphone if only single device is ON.

But For the case if two headphones are ON & If i am connected to one headphone and disconnect the connected headphone I want my second headphone gets automatically connected.

Is there a way to get the peripheral for the connected headphone in phone settings.

I tried by change the port using airplay but found two different name for same headphone.The name found on scanning headphone via core bluetooth is different and name getting via connected port is different.

Spotifiy application is managing the same thing Can anyone please help me out.

I tried by change the port using airplay but found two different name for same headphone.The name found on scanning headphone via core bluetooth is different and name getting via connected port is different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.